# What is the timing curve for [UIView animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping...]

Tags: ios, animation, appearance

The curve that it uses superficially appears to be a damped oscillator, except that you are able to specify the duration of the animation and it always ends up at the target on time. It also reaches the point regardless of the damping you set, without either delay at the end or (I don't think) being interrupted at the end.

So, does anyone have any idea how a curve like this is calculated? Can it be done simply by putting some more clever coefficients into a damped spring? I want to be able to write my own version to support iOS <7 with the same quality of behavior, and would like to replicate it as closely as possible.